# Need help in building a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have one table that contains two columns:

- item ID
- item Name

I have another products table that has three columns:

- product name
- item id 1
- item id 2

I want to build a query that will show this:

- product name
- item name for item id 1
- item name for item id 2

How do I do this?

Comment: Look into the JOIN syntax. Like Mr. Ponies said, this is a very basic query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ProductName, a1.ItemName AS Item1, a2.ItemName AS Item2
FROM Products
    INNER JOIN Items a1 ON Products.ItemsID1 = a1.ItemID 
    INNER JOIN Items a2 ON Products.ItemsID2 = a2.ItemID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.name, i1.name, i2.name from products p
join items i1 on i1.id=p.item1_id
join items i2 on i2.id=p.item2_id
where p.id=?;
```

replace ? with your parameter.
enjoy,